# Shapiro time delay for signal with velocity $v<c$? (updated)

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

Consider appendix A in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.5597.pdf).

Here a situation is considered where a particle is moving along the red $z$-direction, while experiencing the symmetric gravitational potential of two massive particles in a transverse direction:

[image]

Assuming a simple superposition of two Schwarzschild solutions for the black dots, the authors suggest an approximate metric

[image]

where the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$ of both black dots is assumed to be small. Coordinate $z$ enters as $r=\sqrt{b^2+z^2}$ and $b$ is the distance as shown in the picture.

Then, assuming a particle that moves with velocity $v$, the authors simply write down the equations:

[image]

The first equation can be understood as $d\tau^2=ds^2$ equation for the particle involving only the dynamical variables from the metric. But there seems to be a typo: Note that from equation (A.2) follows that the first equation in (A.5) should actually read:

$$dt^2(1-2\frac{r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}})=dz^2(1+2\frac{r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}}\frac{z^2}{z^2+b^2})+d\tau^2$$
(there was a factor of 2 missing in the parentheses on the right hand side).

The second line seems to be the [proper time equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time#In_general_relativity). **However, isn't there a square root missing around the explicit $g_{00}$ component? Or, rather, it seems to be missing a bunch of terms.**

The third line needs to be integrated to obtain the Shapiro time delay, and its derivation can be understood as follows. Note that in flat space, where $r_s=0$, we have

$$d\tau=dt/\gamma~~~\text{and it follows that}~~~dt=dz/v$$

Since we are working at leading order in $r_s^{D-3}$, this means wherever $dt^2$ multiplies $r_s^{D-3}$ we can use the flat space result $r_s^{D-3}dt^2=r_s^{D-3}dz^2/v^2$ to substitute. Then one can check that, simply assuming the second line in (A.5), plugging into the corrected first line above, performing $r_s^{D-3}dt^2=r_s^{D-3}dz^2/v^2$ substitutions, solving for $dt$ and expanding the square root in a series, gives exactly the third line in (A.5).

Therefore, only the question remains:

> How does the second line in (A.5) come about exactly?

Put another way, in order to recover

$$dt^2(1-2\frac{r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}})=dz^2(1+2\frac{r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}}\frac{z^2}{z^2+b^2})+d\tau^2$$

from the second equation in (A.5), $v^2$ must be given by

$$v^2=\frac{dz^2}{dt^2}(1+\frac{4r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}}+\frac{2r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}}\frac{z^2}{z^2+b^2})-\frac{2r_s^{D-3}}{r^{D-3}}$$

So that the question becomes:

> How can one see that the above is the correct definition for $v^2$ in the metric that is perturbed away from the flat case?

Since we assume $D\geq 4$, the flat space limit $r_s=0$ reduces correctly to what we expect.

Comment: Please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301), just seamlessly edit the new content into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you for this suggestion. I have edited the question and adjusted it as you suggest.